# Catalan number coefficient extraction using transfer theorem

Tags: generating-functions, catalan-numbers, analytic-combinatorics

Once again my troubles are with 
$$[z^n]\frac{f(z)}{(1-z/p)^\alpha}\sim \frac{f(p)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1}p^n$$

In Sedgewick and Flajolet's book, they claim that this formula allows us to go, ignoring the constant from:

$$ (1- \sqrt{1-4x})/2$$ to $$ 4^n/(n\sqrt{n\pi })$$

I didn't quite get this:

1) Isn't $p$ here 1/4, so we would end up with $4^{-n}$ instead?

2) Shouldn't the catalan recurrence be $ (1- \sqrt{1-4x})/2x$ ? Does this x make a difference to the application of the formula?

Cheers

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you (1) cite the specific book (there are at least two by Sedgewick and Flajolet) and (2) state the page number of the formula(s) that are giving you difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transfer theorem should be
$$[z^n]\frac{f(z)}{(1-z/p)^\alpha}\sim \frac{f(p)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1}p^{\color\red {-n}}$$
and the generating function for the Catalan numbers should be 
$$(1- \sqrt{1-4x})/(\color\red{2x})$$
which does make a difference in the application of the theorem, as you surmised.

Comment: While your answer makes sense for my calculation, the book, as well as the coursera video AND the princeton powerpoint present it as (p^n). Do you have some source, or a justification of why it is p^-n so I can be assured that what you say is correct? Thank you

Comment: @ConfusedSoul Which book?

Comment: An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms, Chapter 5.5 Generating Function Coefficient Asymptotics

Comment: @ConfusedSoul There is an errata sheet for "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" here: https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/errata/.  See the correction to the corollary on page 250.

Comment: I did not expect the book to be mistaken. I will be more skeptical in the future

Comment: It should indeed be $p^{-n}$, where $ p$ is the dominant singularity of $f(z)$. Some time, authors like to write the asymptotic estimate with $q^n$ instead, where $q = p^{-1}$, so that the exponential term is clearly visible.